# Debugging Namespace Extensions using Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, com, namespaces

What is the best way to debug a namespace extension using Visual Studio? It's not convenient to use regsvr32 to register and unregister the extension and to restart the Explorer for each and every build. Attaching the debugger to the extension would be a nice benefit.

Is there a simple way to debug a namespace extension using Visual Studio?

Comment: It would help if you give a bit more detail about what are you trying to do. Why do you need to register your dll's for example, etc.

Comment: I am writing a namespace extension that adds a new virtual folder to the explorer. This is done use a dll that is registered as COM-server.
My Problem is that I did not find a way to debug this extension using Visual Studio. When rebuilding my Project I have got to kill the explorer because the dll is loaded. I cannot attach the debugger to this process either.
I'd like to know if there is a simple way to start and debug such namespace extensions.

Comment: I haven't tried it in that context, but why don't you specify in the project properties explorer.exe  as "Start action|Start external program". You will have to specify the exact path (say "C:\Winnt\explorer.exe") and most probably that should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start explorer with something like `explorer.exe /separate,::{desktopguid}\::{yourguid}` you should get a separate process for that window and it should pick up new  registry entries (or existing entries if you just leave them in there, you could then add a `GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetShellWindow(),...)!=GetCurrentProcessId()` check and not load in the "main" shell process).

There are also some registry values you can set to change the behavior of explorer: [DesktopProcess](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc938262.aspx), SeparateProcess and BrowseNewProcess

To close down the shell without killing the process in taskmgr, use this old shutdown trick: Click Start, and then Shut Down. Hold down Ctrl+Alt+Shift and click Cancel